# Modifying inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-remote

I have a dockerized Nodejs application and I deploy it on a remote server using the following command:
`docker run -p 3000:3000 -d --mount source=<dev-volume-name>,target=//data --restart always <docker-image>`

I followed the instruction to 'Attach to a running container' in the VS Code documentation. I am able to connect properly and I am able to open the `WORKDIR` where I have the app files.
I am monitoring the logs using 'docker logs <containerID>'

However, If I change something in the source code (like add a console.error('Some message')) it does not show up in the logs. How Can I make changes to file so the Node app is compiled again inside the container?
(since the changes I made are not making any difference, I am assuming new changes are not being compiled)

Also, is it possible to attach to the `npm run start` process in the container

This is my `DockerFile`

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS deps

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json  ./
RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm run postinstall
RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app


ENV NODE_ENV production


COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# C Dependencies & Node Installation
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gcc g++ gnupg unixodbc-dev nodejs

# Python Dependencies
COPY 'some python files'
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules

ENV NODE_ENV production

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000


CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: Why do you need to do development both on a remote server and inside a container?  Can you set up a local non-container Node environment, check out your code locally, develop locally, and then build and push an image to run on the remote machine once it works?

Comment: The image build takes a lot  of time